# Tensorflow: tf.reduce_logsumexp returning negative values

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow framework. I am using 
    `tf.reduce_logsumexp` in my code. But inspecting the output I see that some of the values are negative. How is that possible? I suspected that it might be due to some `nans` or `inf` values so I put in a check to remove those values in my input like this(`X` is my input):

```
res = tf.where(tf.is_inf(X), tf.zeros_like(X), X)
res = tf.where(tf.is_nan(res), tf.zeros_like(res), res)
output = tf.reduce_logsumexp(res, axis=0)
```

But even this does not help and I still get some values as negative. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Note that `tf.reduce_logsumexp([-1.])` is -1

Answer (score 0):

Note that the logarithm is negative, if its argument is smaller than 1. Therefore, you will always get a negative `logsumexp` output if the sum of the exponentials is smaller than 1. This occurs for example if all of the exponents are much smaller than zero, i.e. you have

res = [-2.5, -1.4, -3.3, -1.65, -2.15], then the corresponding exponentials are

exp(res) = [0.082, 0.247, 0.037, 0.192, 0.116], and their sum

sum(exp(res)) = 0.674 smaller than 1.

If you then take the logarithm, you get 
log(sum(exp(res))) = log(0.674) = -0.394.

It simply emerges from the definition of the function that it does not necessarily have a positive output. You can test it with the following program:

```
import numpy as np

def logsumexp(arr):
    summ = 0.0
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        print(np.exp(arr[i]))
        summ += np.exp(arr[i])
    print('Sum: {}'.format(summ))
    return np.log(np.sum(np.exp(arr)))

arr = np.asarray([-2.5, -1.4, -3.3, -1.65, -2.15])
print('LogSumExp: {}'.format(logsumexp(arr)))
```